# Using "sea legs" figuratively

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In most dictionaries, the plural noun "sea legs" refers to the ability to keep balance while walking on the deck of a moving ship.

My question is whether we can use it figuratively to describe general situations that may happen in our everyday life. For example, would it be correct to say:

> *Finally, Jane found her sea legs after years of emotional instability.*

Comment: Just about any expression can be used figuratively. But be careful how you use it: "After a dizzying sickness, she found her sea legs while rummaging through a trunk of her mother's mementos" is going to occasion some laughter.

Comment: The example sentence in the OP is not a great one. A better example would be *Cut him some slack, he just started this job two weeks ago; he hasn't found his sea legs yet.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes.**

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sea+legs) gives the figurative use:

> **sea legs**
>
> The ability to adjust to a new situation or difficult conditions, as in *She's only spoken in public a few times; she hasn't found her sea legs yet*. This expression was first recorded in 1712 and then referred to, as it still does, the ability to walk steadily on board ship, especially in rough seas. By the late 1800s it was being transferred to other challenging situations.

Comment: Referring to the OP's Jane example, I think it'd be a better fit if it was clear what new external environment was causing her problems.

Comment: @CCTO the question asks about using "sea legs" figuratively. I don't see what the actual problems of Jane in the example have to do with it. Anyway, there is no mention of a new environment causing problems – far from it, Jane has now found stability. In this context, the phrase "found her sea legs" means Jane can now travel confidently through life.

Comment: While this answer is correct that 'sea legs' **can** be used figuratively, I don't think the OP's example sounds very natural (native speaker, British English). I think if you want to use 'sea legs' in a context other than being aboard a ship, you need to specify the context. I think this is the same issue CCTO is raising.

Comment: Something like '*after years of emotional instability making her struggle in relationships, Jane finally found her sea legs in 2020*' sounds much more natural to me. I would understand the OP's sentence but find it confusing and jarring.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Sea legs" in the literal sense refers to the *transition* from solid ground to the rocking, swaying surface of a ship. It makes most sense to use it when someone has gone from a familiar external environment to a new, unfamiliar one, like CCTO said. "Using a phrase figuratively" doesn't mean "using the phrase in an arbitrary way with little relationship to the original usage".

Comment: @RiversMcForge I don't think so – more a transition from swaying deck to apparently steady, and perhaps after several days at sea. The figurative sense need have nothing to with the sea. The question asks if it *can* be used figuratively, and in the example Jane has transitioned from an unsteady state to a stable one. Their sentence may be slightly awkward, but the usage does fit.